# Sort files in numeric order

Tags: java, sorting

I made a program to combine all files in a folder together.

Here's part of my code:

```
File folder = new File("c:/some directory");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
for (File file : listOfFiles){

if (file.isFile()){
    System.out.println(file.getName());
    File f = new File("c:/some directory"+file.getName());
```

However, I hope my files can be in order of like:
job1.script, job2.script, .....

but I get:
job1.script, job10.script, job11.script, that 10,11,12... are in front of 2.

I hope I can get efficient code that can avoid this problem.

Comment: Sort list of files listOfFiles on the basis of numeric order

Comment: You can use `Arrays.sort` with a custom `Comparator`

Answer (score 6):

Time to get rid of all the clumpsy code, and use Java 8! This answer also features the `Path` class, which is already part of Java 7, however seems to be heavily improved in Java 8.

The code:

```
private void init() throws IOException {
    Path directory = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Frank\\Downloads\\testjob");
    Files.list(directory)
            .filter(path -> Files.isRegularFile(path))
            .filter(path -> path.getFileName().toString().startsWith("job"))
            .filter(path -> path.getFileName().toString().endsWith(".script"))
            .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(this::pathToInt))
            .map(path -> path.getFileName())
            .forEach(System.out::println);
}

private int pathToInt(final Path path) {
    return Integer.parseInt(path.getFileName()
            .toString()
            .replace("job", "")
            .replace(".script", "")
    );
}
```

The explanation of `pathToInt`:

1. From a given `Path`, obtain the String representation of the file.
2. Remove `"job"` and `".script"`.
3. Try to parse the String as an Integer.

The explanation of `init`, the main method:

1. Obtain a `Path` to the directory where the files are located.
2. Obtain a lazily populated list of `Path`s in the directory, be aware: These `Path`s are still fully qualified!
3. Keep files that are regular files.
4. Keep files of which the last part of the `Path`, thus the filename (for example `job1.script`) starts with `"job"`. **Be aware** that you need to first obtain the String representation of the `Path` before you can check it, else you will be checking if the whole `Path` starts with a directory called `"job"`.
5. Do the same for files ending with `".script"`.
6. Now comes the fun point. Here we sort the file list based on a `Comparator` that compares the integers which we obtain by calling `pathToInt` on the `Path`. Here I am using a method reference, the method `comparingInt(ToIntFunction<? super T> keyExtractor` expects a function that maps a `T`, in this case a `Path`, to an int. And this is exactly what `pathToInt` does, hence it can be used a method reference.
7. Then I map every `Path` to the `Path` only consisting of the filename.
8. Lastly, for each element of the `Stream<Path>`, I call `System.out.println(Path.toString())`.

It may seem like this code could be written easier, however I have purposefully written it more verbose. My design here is to keep the full `Path` intact at all times, the very last part of the code in the `forEach` actually violates that principle as shortly before it gets mapped to only the file name, and hence you are not able to process the full `Path` anymore at a later point.

This code is also designed to be fail-fast, hence it is expecting files to be there in the form `job(\D+).script`, and will throw a `NumberFormatException` if that is not the case.

Example output:

```
job1.script
job2.script
job10.script
job11.script
```

An arguably better alternative features the power of regular expressions:

```
private void init() throws IOException {
    Path directory = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Frank\\Downloads\\testjob");
    Files.list(directory)
            .filter(path -> Files.isRegularFile(path))
            .filter(path -> path.getFileName().toString().matches("job\\d+.script"))
            .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(this::pathToInt))
            .map(path -> path.getFileName())
            .forEach(System.out::println);
}

private int pathToInt(final Path path) {
    return Integer.parseInt(path.getFileName()
            .toString()
            .replaceAll("job(\\d+).script", "$1")
    );
}
```

Here I use the regular expression `"job\\d+.script"`, which matches a string starting with `"job"`, followed by one or more digits, followed by ".script".
I use almost the same expression for the `pathToInt` method, however there I use a capturing group, the parentheses, and `$1` to use that capturing group.

I will also provide a concise way to read the contents of the files in one big file, as you have also asked in your question:

```
private void init() throws IOException {
    Path directory = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Frank\\Downloads\\testjob");
    try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(directory.resolve("masterjob.script"))) {
        Files.list(directory)
                .filter(path -> Files.isRegularFile(path))
                .filter(path -> path.getFileName().toString().matches("job\\d+.script"))
                .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(this::pathToInt))
                .flatMap(this::wrappedLines)
                .forEach(string -> wrappedWrite(writer, string));
    }
}

private int pathToInt(final Path path) {
    return Integer.parseInt(path.getFileName()
            .toString()
            .replaceAll("job(\\d+).script", "$1")
    );
}

private Stream<String> wrappedLines(final Path path) {
    try {
        return Files.lines(path);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        //swallow
        return null;
    }
}

private void wrappedWrite(final BufferedWriter writer, final String string) {
    try {
        writer.write(string);
        writer.newLine();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        //swallow
    }
}
```

Please note that lambdas cannot throw/catch checked `Exception`s, hence there is a neccessity to write wrappers around the code, that decides what to do with the errors. Swallowing the exceptions is rarely a good idea, I am just using it here for code simplicitely.

The real big change here is that instead of printing out the names, I map every file to its contents and write those to a file.

Answer (score 2):

If your files' name are always like `jobNumber.script` you could sort the `array` providing a custom comparator:

```
Arrays.sort(listOfFiles, new Comparator<File>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
            String s1 = f1.getName().substring(3, f1.getName().indexOf("."));
            String s2 = f2.getName().substring(3, f2.getName().indexOf("."));
            return Integer.valueOf(s1).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(s2));  
        }
});
```

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        File folder = new File(".");
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {            
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File arg0, String arg1) {
                return arg1.endsWith(".script");
            }
        });
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(listOfFiles));
        Arrays.sort(listOfFiles, new Comparator<File>(){
            @Override
            public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
                String s1 = f1.getName().substring(3, f1.getName().indexOf("."));
                String s2 = f2.getName().substring(3, f2.getName().indexOf("."));
                return Integer.valueOf(s1).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(s2));  
            }
        });
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(listOfFiles));
    }
```

Prints:

```
[.\job1.script, .\job1444.script, .\job4.script, .\job452.script, .\job77.script]
[.\job1.script, .\job4.script, .\job77.script, .\job452.script, .\job1444.script]
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to zero pad all digits lower than 10. Like

```
job01.script
```

instead of

```
job1.script
```

This assumes no more than 100 files. With more, simply add more zeros.

Otherwise, you'll need analyze and breakdown each file name, and then order it *numerically*. Currently, it's being ordered by *character*.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method to solve this problem is to prefix your names with `0`s. This is what I did when I had the same problem. So basically you choose the biggest number you have (for example `433234`) and prefix all numbers with `biggestLength - currentNumLength` zeroes.

An example:

Biggest number is `12345`: `job12345.script`.

This way the first job becomes `job00001.script`.