# Regex expression to order files by name (numeric names)

Tags: java, regex

I am compare the file names of some directory and order it. The problem is that every file name is a number, some is 104, others are 5568, others are 50. And they came disorderd at my array. I am using RegexFileFilter to order it, but I need a regex expression to correct it:

What regex can I use? Thanks in advance!

```
String pattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$";
System.out.println("\nFiles that match regular expression: " + pattern);
FileFilter filter = new RegexFileFilter(pattern);
files = directory.listFiles(filter);
displayFiles(files);


Files that match regular expression: ^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$
File: 1048576              Last Modified:Fri Mar 28 14:01:50 BRT 2014
File: 1064960              Last Modified:Fri Mar 28 14:01:50 BRT 2014
File: 1073756160           Last Modified:Fri Mar 28 14:01:47 BRT 2014
File: 1073764352           Last Modified:Fri Mar 28 14:01:48 BRT 2014
File: 1073780736           Last Modified:Fri Mar 28 14:01:28 BRT 2014
File: 1073788928           Last Modified:Fri Mar 28 14:01:28 BRT 2014
File: 1073797120           Last Modified:Fri Mar 28 14:01:28 BRT 2014
File: 1073805312           Last Modified:Fri Mar 28 14:01:28 BRT 2014
File: 1073813504           Last Modified:Fri Mar 28 14:01:28 BRT 2014
File: 1073821696           Last Modified:Fri Mar 28 14:01:29 BRT 2014
File: 537410560            Last Modified:Fri Mar 28 14:01:50 BRT 2014
```

Comment: Regex can't sort/order files, but filter them. Also what is `RegexFileFilter`? This class doesn't belong to standard Java classes.

Comment: If you have the ability to use java 8, you might want to get some information from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22411299/sort-files-in-numeric-order/22413279#22413279

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. to match files which names contain only digits (one or more of them) use `[0-9]+` or `\\d+`

   - `\\d` stands for *digit* and it is similar to range or 0-9 like described in `[0-9]`
   - `+` means "one or more"
2. Regex can be used here to filter files. If you need to sort them later you can just use 
   `Arrays.sort(T[] array)` to sort alphabetically (`"11"` will be before `"2"`) or use
   [`public static <T> void sort(T\[\] a, Comparator<? super T> c)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29) with your own comparator which will convert names to integer and compare them as numbers, something like

   ```
   Comparator<File> nameNumberComparator = new Comparator<File>() {
       @Override
       public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
           return Integer.compare(Integer.valueOf(f1.getName()),
                   Integer.valueOf(f1.getName()));
       }
   };
   ```

   If you have Java 8 you can use lambdas

   ```
   Arrays.sort(files, (f1, f2) -> Integer.compare(
           Integer.valueOf(f1.getName()),
           Integer.valueOf(f2.getName())
   ));
   ```